# Any suggestions with this error? Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

OK, so i keep getting this ajax error and am not sure why.
If i remove the portion of code then the buttons load. I have used this same code before and never had any problems.

Any help would be great.

What I've done so far:

1. looked up "Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function" in stack and took a look at my links to make sure they weren't the cause.
2. Checked that i was loading the code after the page loads (window.onload).
3. Went back to old code where this was working to see if i changed something, i didn't.
4. Google searches.

Note:
I removed the API key in this code but i do have a valid one on my local (tested it to make sure it worked and it did).

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>GIFtastic</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!--Reset style-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../GIFtastic/assets/css/reset.css" />
    <!--Bootstrap-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- My own CSS stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../GIFtastic/assets/css/style.css">
    <!--JavaScript-->
    <script src="../GIFtastic/assets/javascript/app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="dogBtns"></div>    



    <!-- jQuery CDN -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap CDN -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!--popper-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

JS:

```
/*jshint esversion: 6 */
window.onload = function () {
    //1. Before you can make any part of our site work, you need to create an array of strings, each one related to a topic that interests you. Save it to a variable called `topics`.
    //    * We chose animals for our theme, but you can make a list to your own liking.
    var topics = ["Collie", "German Shepherd", "Bernese Mountain Dog", "Australian Shepherd", "Golden Retriever", "Siberian Husky", "Border Collie"];
    var resultNum = 9;

    // 2. Your app should take the topics in this array and create buttons in your HTML.
    // * Try using a loop that appends a button for each string in the array.

    function createTopicBtns() {
        var topicBtns = $("#dogBtns");
        for (i = 0; i < topics.length; i++) {
            var newTopicBtns = $("<button>" + topics[i] + "</buttons>");
            newTopicBtns.attr({
                "type": "button",
                "class": "btn btn-outline-secondary active m-2",
                "data-name": topics[i],
                "text": topics[i]
            });
            console.log(newTopicBtns);
            topicBtns.append(newTopicBtns);
        }
    }

    /*3. When the user clicks on a button, the page should grab 10 static, non-animated gif images from the GIPHY API and place them on the page.
    */

    var queryURL = "https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=collie&api_key=<apiKey>";

    $.ajax({
        url: queryURL,
        method: "GET"
    }).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    });



        /*When the user clicks one of the still GIPHY images, the gif should animate. If the user clicks the gif again, it should stop playing.
        */

        /*Under every gif, display its rating (PG, G, so on).*/

        /*This data is provided by the GIPHY API.
        Only once you get images displaying with button presses should you move on to the next step.
        Add a form to your page takes the value from a user input box and adds it into your topics array. Then make a function call that takes each topic in the array remakes the buttons on the page.
        */

        createTopicBtns();


    //window on load end    
};
```

Comment: jquery slim doesn't include ajax modules

Comment: This fixed it. changed slim to minified.

Answer (score 1):

You are including the jquery code after your javascript code. Doing this is causing your javascript to run before the jquery runs, thus making `$` undefined. Moving your libraries into your header and before your `app.js` should fix the issue.

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>GIFtastic</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!--Reset style-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../GIFtastic/assets/css/reset.css" />
  <!--Bootstrap-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- My own CSS stylesheet -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../GIFtastic/assets/css/style.css">

  <!-- jQuery CDN -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap CDN -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!--popper-->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!--JavaScript-->
  <script src="../GIFtastic/assets/javascript/app.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Doubt this is the reason. $ would be undefined, not $,ajax

Comment: Thanks. I tried that and am getting the same error in the console log.

Comment: like pointed out it is because `slim` doesn't contain `ajax` (which I didn't know either).

Comment: BOOM!
That fixed it!

Changed slim to minified and all is good with the world.